Large LiDAR dataset management in LidR; generating a list of expected output files from catalog_retile
I am hoping to get some help with dealing with a large dataset in lidr. I would like to create CHM and DSM files from this dataset, but because of the amount of memory required to process the dataset, I am first retiling it. Since it is so large, I have been having issues with the script failing part way, leaving me with an incomplete set of retiles files. I am searching for a way to keep track of the output files in a way which would allow me to restart the processing at the correct step using # opt_restart(ctg) <- value #. The issue I am having is that I am not sure how to match the output files to the chunks, as the chunks in this case are the input files which do not share filenames with my output files. currently I am doing the processing in batches so I can restart part way, but I imagine there is a more elegant way to do this. below is my current code. thank you!
library(lidR)
library(future)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Set up parallel processing globally
plan(multisession, workers = availableCores() - 10)  # Use all but 5 cores


# Define directories
source_dir <- "F:/LiDAR/point_cloud/2023"

retiled_dir <- "F:/LiDAR_processing/2023/Retiled_test"

# List all LAS/LAZ files in the directory
source_files <- list.files(source_dir, pattern = "\\.laz$", full.names = FALSE)

file_count <- length(source_files)

# Define some batches every 10
batches <- seq(1, length(source_files), by = 100) %>% 
  .[seq_along(.)]

# Print the result
batches

ctg <- readLAScatalog(source_dir, select = "xyzrnc", )#filter = "-keep_first")  # Load only first returns
summary(ctg)
las_check(ctg)

  opt_filter(ctg) <- "-drop_class 7 18"  # Exclude noise points
  opt_progress(ctg) <- TRUE # so we can see progress
  opt_laz_compression(ctg) <- TRUE  # Enable LAZ compression
  
# Define the output directory for the current batch and create it
batch_dir <- file.path(retiled_dir,"/", as.character(batches[1]))
if (!dir.exists(batch_dir)) {
  dir.create(batch_dir)
}

  opt_output_files(ctg) <- file.path(batch_dir, "{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}")
  opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 20 # set buffer (needed to not produce edge effects)
  opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 250 # set our chunk size in meters 
  
  ctg$processed <- FALSE # set all the chunks to read unprocessed
  ctg$processed[batches[1]:batches[2]] <- TRUE # allows us to only select these range of chunks to be processed
  ctg@output_options$drivers$LAS$param = list(index = TRUE) # sets the lasindex to true to save lasindex files - speeds up processing by not loading ALL of adjacent tiles 

ctg_ret <- catalog_retile(ctg)

# plot(ctg, chunk_pattern=TRUE, mapview = TRUE, map.type = "Esri.WorldImagery")
  
# opt_restart(ctg) <- value # very useful after a crash

# selected_files <- catalog_select(ctg, mapview = TRUE, subset = c("subset", "flag_unprocessed", "flag_processed")) # opens an interactive map to select tiles for processing, returns a new lascatalog


Please have a look on memory usage for each core/worker. My experience shows ~ 4 GB per worker (depending on the chunk size). catalog_retile() function itself doesn't load the .laz files into memory, therefore shouldn't be a big issue.

Thanks for the response. looks like on my machine I am up anywhere from 2 ~ 8 GB per worker (monitoring in task manager, I have a lot of ram).... that didn't actually answer the question I had though, which was about an elegant way to do this. i did adjust the code to save each batch in a separate folder so I could tell how far along in the task my machine was before it crashed/was shut down by some other means
